# Может ли double понимать числа с ' , ' вместо ' . '?

Tags: c++, qt, double

Доброго времени суток.
Реализую калькулятор в Qt. Необходимо вводить, выводить и работать с числами типа double так, чтобы вместо ',' в качестве разделителя была '.'. Это можно как-то сделать? 
Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: А после ввода менять запятые на точки?

Comment: Вот можно ли как-то не меняя?

Comment: Ну, тогда сами обрабатывайте строку из цифр и запятых, превращая ее в значение типа `double`. Вот скажите, `double x[] = { 2,5,2,7,3,15,6};` - каков размер массива? Если можно использовать в `double` запятые?

Comment: А ещё можно задать whitelist вводимых символов. У полей ввода же есть верификаторы.

Comment: Это понятно. Я просто наткнулся на то, что в C# есть изменение языка и региональных параметров текущего потока, что позволяет менять запятую на точку. Вот и подумал вопрос задать.

Comment: QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);

Comment: Есть ряд функций использующих локаль. Нужно пользоваться функциями которые её используют.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Действительно нужно использовать локаль. Например, так

```
double value = QLocale::system().toDouble(str);
```

Comment: Этот код зависит от настроек системы. Он не обязательно сделает десятичный разделитель точкой, разделитель будет тот, который по умолчанию установлен в системе.